# Nexus 4 running CyanogenMod does not take quality photos instantly

Tags: android, android-camera

I am writing an application that takes a picture from the user's front-facing camera as soon as an activity starts. This seems to work on other devices but on my one tester's Nexus 4 running CM, the photos are extremely dark. In fact, the first round of testing we saw all black. A second round of testing on this device showed a blob that corresponded to a light on my tester's ceiling. So this confirms that a photo *is* being taken.

Here is the photo in question: 
[image]

Here is his device info:

```
build.board: MAKO
build.bootloader: MAKOZ10o
build.brand: google
build.cpu_abi: armeabi-v7a
build.cpu_abi2: armeabi
build.device: mako
build.display: cm_mako-userdebug 4.2.2 JDQ39E eng.jenkins.20130904.222637 test-keys
build.fingerprint: google/occam/mako:4.2.2/JDQ39/573038:user/release-keys
build.hardware: mako
build.host: cyanogenmod
build.id: JDQ39E
build.manufacturer: LGE
build.model: Nexus 4
build.product: occam
build.radio: unknown
build.serial: 01ad92a7d1a5f663
build.tags: test-keys
build.time: 1378358851000
build.type: userdebug
build.user: jenkins
version.codename: REL
version.incremental: eng.jenkins.20130904.222637
version.release: 4.2.2
version.sdk_int: 17
```

The application never crashes or throws any fatal exception so I am not sure what exactly is the reason why this is happening. Examining his logs shows a few things that might lead to something:

```
09-21 20:55:15.248 D/overlay (  180): Set pipe=RGB1 dpy=0; Set pipe=VG0 dpy=0; Set pipe=VG1 dpy=0;
09-21 20:55:16.409 D/overlay (  180): Unset pipe=VG0 dpy=0; Unset pipe=VG1 dpy=0; Unset pipe=RGB1 dpy=0;
09-21 20:55:16.439 I/PowerManagerService(  537): Going to sleep by user request...
09-21 20:55:16.970 I/keystore(  185): uid: 1000 action: z -> 7 state: 1 -> 1 retry: 4
09-21 20:55:16.990 D/SurfaceFlinger(  180): Screen released, type=0 flinger=0x2a007318
09-21 20:55:16.990 D/hwcomposer(  180): hwc_blank: Doing Dpy=0, blank=1
09-21 20:55:16.990 I/keystore(  185): uid: 1000 action: z -> 7 state: 1 -> 1 retry: 4
09-21 20:55:17.000 D/overlay (  180): Unset pipe=RGB0 dpy=0;
09-21 20:55:17.000 I/keystore(  185): uid: 1000 action: z -> 7 state: 1 -> 1 retry: 4
09-21 20:55:17.060 D/dalvikvm(32156): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1982K, 46% free 8079K/14732K, paused 1ms+6ms, total 44ms
09-21 20:55:17.160 D/hwcomposer(  180): hwc_blank: Done Dpy=0, blank=1
09-21 20:55:17.160 D/Surface (  537): Excessive delay in blankDisplay() while turning screen off: 4471ms
09-21 20:55:17.190 V/KeyguardHostView(  537): Keyguard widgets disabled by DPM
09-21 20:55:17.190 V/KeyguardHostView(  537): Keyguard secure camera disabled by DPM
09-21 20:55:17.781 D/dalvikvm(  537): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1712K, 37% free 25026K/39164K, paused 19ms+14ms, total 332ms
09-21 20:55:17.781 D/dalvikvm(  537): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 152ms
09-21 20:55:17.821 I/keystore(  185): uid: 1000 action: z -> 7 state: 1 -> 1 retry: 4
09-21 20:55:17.831 W/ActivityManager(  537): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{40d446e0 u0 com.nolanlawson.logcat/.LogcatActivity}
09-21 20:55:17.931 I/keystore(  185): uid: 1000 action: z -> 7 state: 1 -> 1 retry: 4
09-21 20:55:18.071 I/keystore(  185): uid: 1000 action: z -> 7 state: 1 -> 1 retry: 4
09-21 20:55:18.101 I/keystore(  185): uid: 1000 action: z -> 7 state: 1 -> 1 retry: 4
09-21 20:55:18.121 I/keystore(  185): uid: 1000 action: z -> 7 state: 1 -> 1 retry: 4
09-21 20:55:18.141 I/keystore(  185): uid: 1000 action: z -> 7 state: 1 -> 1 retry: 4
09-21 20:55:18.151 I/keystore(  185): uid: 1000 action: z -> 7 state: 1 -> 1 retry: 4
09-21 20:55:18.171 D/PhoneStatusBar(  831): disable: < EXPAND* icons alerts TICKER* system_info back home RECENT* clock search >
09-21 20:55:18.321 V/TAG     (  537): bug 7643792: fitSystemWindows([0,50][0,0])
09-21 20:55:18.341 D/PhoneStatusBar(  831): disable: < EXPAND icons alerts TICKER system_info BACK* HOME* RECENT CLOCK* search >
09-21 20:55:18.371 V/KeyguardHostView(  537): Keyguard widgets disabled by DPM
09-21 20:55:18.371 V/KeyguardHostView(  537): Keyguard secure camera disabled by DPM
09-21 20:55:18.642 I/keystore(  185): uid: 1000 action: z -> 7 state: 1 -> 1 retry: 4
09-21 20:55:18.672 I/keystore(  185): uid: 1000 action: z -> 7 state: 1 -> 1 retry: 4
09-21 20:55:18.752 I/keystore(  185): uid: 1000 action: z -> 7 state: 1 -> 1 retry: 4
09-21 20:55:18.762 I/keystore(  185): uid: 1000 action: z -> 7 state: 1 -> 1 retry: 4
09-21 20:55:18.842 I/PowerManagerService(  537): Waking up from sleep...
09-21 20:55:18.852 I/keystore(  185): uid: 1000 action: z -> 7 state: 1 -> 1 retry: 4
09-21 20:55:18.882 D/SurfaceFlinger(  180): Screen acquired, type=0 flinger=0x2a007318
09-21 20:55:19.062 D/overlay (  180): Set pipe=RGB0 dpy=0;
09-21 20:55:19.112 I/USERIAL_LINUX(  989): USERIAL_Open(): enter
09-21 20:55:19.112 I/USERIAL_LINUX(  989): USERIAL_Open() device: /dev/bcm2079x-i2c port=5, uart_port=0 WAKE_DELAY(20) WRITE_DELAY(20) POWER_ON_DELAY(300) PRE_POWER_OFF_DELAY(10) POST_POWER_OFF_DELAY(0)
09-21 20:55:19.132 I/WindowManager(  537): Lock screen displayed!
09-21 20:55:19.162 D/overlay (  180): Set pipe=RGB1 dpy=0; Set pipe=VG0 dpy=0; Set pipe=VG1 dpy=0;
09-21 20:55:19.182 I/keystore(  185): uid: 1000 action: z -> 7 state: 1 -> 1 retry: 4
09-21 20:55:19.312 D/dalvikvm(18909): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1995K, 41% free 6393K/10660K, paused 4ms+4ms, total 49ms
09-21 20:55:19.312 D/dalvikvm(18909): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 33ms
09-21 20:55:19.723 I/USERIAL_LINUX(  989): USERIAL_Open(): exit
09-21 20:55:23.997 I/keystore(  185): uid: 1000 action: z -> 7 state: 1 -> 1 retry: 4
09-21 20:55:24.017 D/DeviceAdminMgr(32103): Bad Password observed. This is 1/1
09-21 20:55:24.017 I/ActivityManager(  537): START u0 {flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.jknipp.jkat/.cameraInterfaceActivity} from pid 32103
09-21 20:55:24.117 E/MediaPlayer(  183): error (1, -2147483648)
09-21 20:55:24.117 I/CameraClient(  183): Opening camera 1
09-21 20:55:24.127 I/BugSenseHandler(32103): Flushing...
09-21 20:55:24.127 I/BugSenseHandler(32103): Registering default exceptions handler
09-21 20:55:24.167 E/mm-camera(  208): DSPS has already been initialized
09-21 20:55:24.177 W/Sensors ( 4927): sns_smr_la.c(467):smr_la: poll return revents: 0x8/0 errno: 0
09-21 20:55:24.177 W/Sensors ( 4927): sns_main.c(1309):sns_main_exit called
09-21 20:55:24.177 E/Sensors ( 4927): sns_main.c(1389):Exiting!
09-21 20:55:24.207 E/mm-camera(  208): sensor_load_chromatix: libchromatix_imx119_preview.so: 30
09-21 20:55:24.217 E/mm-camera(  208): dsps_handle_broken_pipe: Broken Pipe Exception
09-21 20:55:24.217 W/qcom_sensors_hal(  537): hal_sensor1_data_cb: SENSOR1_MSG_TYPE_BROKEN_PIPE
09-21 20:55:24.227 E/Sensors ( 5262): sns_fsa_la.c(355):fsa: fflush failed, 9
09-21 20:55:24.227 E/Sensors ( 5262): sns_fsa_la.c(355):fsa: fflush failed, 9
09-21 20:55:24.227 E/mm-camera(  208): vfe_ops_init: E
09-21 20:55:24.227 E/mm-camera(  208): vfe_legacy_stats_buffer_init: AEC_STATS_BUFNUM
09-21 20:55:24.227 E/mm-camera(  208): vfe_legacy_stats_buffer_init: AEC_STATS_BUFNUM
09-21 20:55:24.237 E/mm-camera(  208): mctl_init_stats_proc_info: snap_max_line_cnt =25776
09-21 20:55:24.247 I/JKAT    (32103): getCameraInstance called
09-21 20:55:24.247 I/JKAT    (32103): Returning found camera instance
09-21 20:55:24.277 W/Sensors ( 5262): sns_smr_la.c(446):smr_la: smr_apps_la_thread_main is starting, fd=15, sns_smr.en_rx_msg_ptr=2a0418b8
09-21 20:55:24.287 E/QCameraHWI(  183): android::status_t android::QCameraHardwareInterface::setPreviewWindow(preview_stream_ops_t*): mPreviewWindow = 0x0x2a094f98, mStreamDisplay = 0x0x2a075988
09-21 20:55:24.287 D/QCameraHWI(  183): android::status_t android::QCameraHardwareInterface::startPreview():  start preview now
09-21 20:55:24.287 I/QCameraHWI(  183): android::status_t android::QCameraHardwareInterface::startPreview2():Setting ZSL mode
09-21 20:55:24.287 E/mm-camera(  208): config_proc_CAMERA_SET_INFORM_STARTPREVIEW
09-21 20:55:24.287 E/mm-camera(  208): config_update_stream_info Storing stream parameters for video inst 1 as : width = 640, height 480, format = 1 inst_handle = 810081 cid = 0
09-21 20:55:24.307 E/mm-camera(  208): config_update_stream_info Storing stream parameters for video inst 3 as : width = 640, height 480, format = 1 inst_handle = 830083 cid = 0
09-21 20:55:24.307 E/mm-camera(  208): config_update_stream_info Storing stream parameters for video inst 4 as : width = 512, height 384, format = 1 inst_handle = 840084 cid = 0
09-21 20:55:24.307 E/mm-camera(  208): config_decide_vfe_outputs: Ports Used 3, Op mode 1
09-21 20:55:24.307 E/mm-camera(  208): config_decide_vfe_outputs Current mode 0 Full size streaming : Disabled
09-21 20:55:24.307 E/mm-camera(  208): config_decide_vfe_outputs: Primary: 640x480, extra_pad: 0x0, Fmt: 1, Type: 1, Path: 1
09-21 20:55:24.307 E/mm-camera(  208): config_decide_vfe_outputs: Secondary: 640x480, extra_pad: 0x0, Fmt: 1, Type: 3, Path: 4
09-21 20:55:24.307 E/mm-camera(  208): config_update_inst_handles Updated the inst handles as 810081, 830083, 0, 0
09-21 20:55:24.427 E/mm-camera(  208): sensor_load_chromatix: libchromatix_imx119_preview.so: 30
09-21 20:55:24.427 E/mm-camera(  208): camif_client_set_params: camif has associated with obj mask 0x1
09-21 20:55:24.427 E/mm-camera(  208): config_v2_CAMERA_START_common CAMIF_PARAMS_ADD_OBJ_ID failed -1
09-21 20:55:24.427 E/mm-camera(  208): vfe_operation_config: format 3
09-21 20:55:24.427 E/mm-camera(  208): vfe_operation_config:vfe_op_mode=5
09-21 20:55:24.427 E/mm-camera(  208): Invalid ASD Set Params Type
09-21 20:55:24.427 E/mm-camera(  208): vfe_set_bestshot: Bestshot mode not changed
09-21 20:55:24.447 D/CameraPreview(32103): SurfaceChanged called
09-21 20:55:24.447 E/mm-libcamera2(  183): PROFILE HAL: stopPreview(): E: 1379822124.461927772
09-21 20:55:24.447 E/mm-camera(  208): config_MSG_ID_STOP_ACK: streamon_mask is not clear. Should not call PP_Release_HW
09-21 20:55:24.457 E/QCameraHWI(  183): android::status_t android::QCameraHardwareInterface::setPreviewWindow(preview_stream_ops_t*): mPreviewWindow = 0x0x2a094f98, mStreamDisplay = 0x0x2a075988
09-21 20:55:24.457 D/QCameraHWI(  183): android::status_t android::QCameraHardwareInterface::startPreview():  start preview now
09-21 20:55:24.457 I/QCameraHWI(  183): android::status_t android::QCameraHardwareInterface::startPreview2():Setting ZSL mode
09-21 20:55:24.457 E/mm-camera(  208): config_proc_CAMERA_SET_INFORM_STARTPREVIEW
09-21 20:55:24.467 E/mm-camera(  208): config_update_stream_info Storing stream parameters for video inst 1 as : width = 640, height 480, format = 1 inst_handle = 810081 cid = 0
09-21 20:55:24.477 E/mm-camera(  208): config_update_stream_info Storing stream parameters for video inst 3 as : width = 640, height 480, format = 1 inst_handle = 830083 cid = 0
09-21 20:55:24.477 E/mm-camera(  208): config_update_stream_info Storing stream parameters for video inst 4 as : width = 512, height 384, format = 1 inst_handle = 840084 cid = 0
09-21 20:55:24.487 E/mm-camera(  208): config_decide_vfe_outputs: Ports Used 3, Op mode 1
09-21 20:55:24.487 E/mm-camera(  208): config_decide_vfe_outputs Current mode 5 Full size streaming : Disabled
09-21 20:55:24.487 E/mm-camera(  208): config_decide_vfe_outputs: Primary: 640x480, extra_pad: 0x0, Fmt: 1, Type: 1, Path: 1
09-21 20:55:24.487 E/mm-camera(  208): config_decide_vfe_outputs: Secondary: 640x480, extra_pad: 0x0, Fmt: 1, Type: 3, Path: 4
09-21 20:55:24.487 E/mm-camera(  208): config_update_inst_handles Updated the inst handles as 810081, 830083, 0, 0
09-21 20:55:24.487 E/mm-camera(  208): camif_client_set_params: camif has associated with obj mask 0x1
09-21 20:55:24.487 E/mm-camera(  208): config_v2_CAMERA_START_common CAMIF_PARAMS_ADD_OBJ_ID failed -1
09-21 20:55:24.487 E/mm-camera(  208): vfe_operation_config: format 3
09-21 20:55:24.487 E/mm-camera(  208): vfe_operation_config:vfe_op_mode=5
09-21 20:55:24.547 E/mm-libcamera2(  183): PROFILE HAL: First preview frame received: 1379822124.557173133
09-21 20:55:24.547 E/BufferQueue(  180): [SurfaceView] dequeueBuffer: min undequeued buffer count (2) exceeded (dequeued=6 undequeudCount=0)
09-21 20:55:24.597 E/mm-libcamera2(  183): mm_camera_dispatch_buffered_frames: mframe 0x0, sframe = 0x0
09-21 20:55:24.617 D/morpho_NoiseReduction_Version (  183): = Morpho Denoiser for LGE mako Ver.1.0.2   2012/10/10
09-21 20:55:24.617 E/BufferQueue(  180): [SurfaceView] dequeueBuffer: min undequeued buffer count (2) exceeded (dequeued=5 undequeudCount=1)
09-21 20:55:24.617 D/morpho_NoiseReduction_getBufferSize = (  183): 195292
09-21 20:55:24.617 D/morpho_NoiseReduction_getBufferSize buffer malloc = (  183): 2a0b0788
09-21 20:55:24.617 D/morpho_NoiseReduction_initialize (  183): EngineVersion= Morpho Denoiser for LGE mako Ver.1.0.2   2012/10/10
09-21 20:55:24.617 D/Version info :(  183): Morpho Denoiser for LGE mako Ver.1.0.2   2012/10/10
09-21 20:55:24.617 D/morpho_NoiseReduction_initialize ret = (  183): 0
09-21 20:55:24.617 D/morpho_NoiseReduction_initialize IMAGE_FORMAT = (  183): YVU420_SEMIPLANAR
09-21 20:55:24.617 D/morpho_NoiseReduction_setLumaNoiseReductionLevel y_level for LGE = (  183): 0
09-21 20:55:24.617 D/morpho_NoiseReduction_setChromaNoiseReductionLevel c_level = (  183): 1
09-21 20:55:24.617 D/morpho_NoiseReduction_setRemoveSpikeNoise SpikeNoise = (  183): 1
09-21 20:55:24.617 D/morpho_NoiseReduction allocateImage c_level = (  183): 0
09-21 20:55:24.617 D/morpho_NoiseReduction_start  ret = (  183): 0
09-21 20:55:24.647 I/ActivityManager(  537): Displayed com.jknipp.jkat/.cameraInterfaceActivity: +616ms
09-21 20:55:24.718 D/morpho_NoiseReduction_reduceNoise  ret = (  183): 0
09-21 20:55:24.718 D/morpho_NoiseReduction_finalize  ret = (  183): 0
09-21 20:55:24.718 W/CameraClient(  183): lockIfMessageWanted(2): dropped unwanted message
09-21 20:55:24.718 E/mm-camera-DENOISE(  208): [QCTK] Wavelet pre_real_gain = 6.827942
09-21 20:55:24.718 E/mm-camera-DENOISE(  208): [QCTK] Wavelet Trigger referencePatchAverageValue = 1.000000
09-21 20:55:24.718 E/mm-camera-DENOISE(  208): [QCTK] Wavelet Trigger referencePatchAverageValue = 2.000000
09-21 20:55:24.718 E/mm-camera-DENOISE(  208): [QCTK] Wavelet Trigger referencePatchAverageValue = 3.000000
09-21 20:55:24.718 E/mm-camera-DENOISE(  208): [QCTK] Wavelet Trigger referencePatchAverageValue = 4.000000
09-21 20:55:24.718 E/mm-camera-DENOISE(  208): [QCTK] Wavelet Trigger referencePatchAverageValue = 8.000000
09-21 20:55:24.718 E/mm-camera-DENOISE(  208): [QCTK] Wavelet Trigger Patch_index = 4,
09-21 20:55:24.718 E/mm-camera-DENOISE(  208): [QCTK] WNR gain = 1, denoise_scale_Y: 3 denoise_scale_Chroma: 3 low= 4.000000, high= 8.000000,calibration_level= 6.82794
09-21 20:55:24.718 E/mm-camera-DENOISE(  208): [QCTK] WNR Y Profile data[0] = 5242387 Chroma Profile data[0] = 5242387
09-21 20:55:24.718 E/mm-camera-DENOISE(  208): [QCTK] WNR Y Profile data[1] = 8919208 Chroma Profile data[1] = 8919208
09-21 20:55:24.718 E/mm-camera-DENOISE(  208): [QCTK] WNR Y Profile data[2] = 14557674 Chroma Profile data[2] = 14557674
09-21 20:55:24.718 E/mm-camera-DENOISE(  208): [QCTK] WNR Y Profile data[3] = 20974330 Chroma Profile data[3] = 20974330
09-21 20:55:24.718 E/mm-camera-DENOISE(  208): [QCTK] WNR Y Profile data[4] = 2838201 Chroma Profile data[4] = 2838201
09-21 20:55:24.718 E/mm-camera-DENOISE(  208): [QCTK] WNR Y Profile data[5] = 5260884 Chroma Profile data[5] = 5260884
09-21 20:55:24.718 E/mm-camera-DENOISE(  208): [QCTK] WNR Y Profile data[6] = 11775592 Chroma Profile data[6] = 11775592
09-21 20:55:24.718 E/mm-camera-DENOISE(  208): [QCTK] WNR Y Profile data[7] = 12825007 Chroma Profile data[7] = 12825007
09-21 20:55:24.718 E/mm-camera-DENOISE(  208): [QCTK] WNR Y Profile data[8] = 5218353 Chroma Profile data[8] = 5218353
09-21 20:55:24.718 E/mm-camera-DENOISE(  208): [QCTK] WNR Y Profile data[9] = 12416125 Chroma Profile data[9] = 12416125
09-21 20:55:24.718 E/mm-camera-DENOISE(  208): [QCTK] WNR Y Profile data[10] = 57849654 Chroma Profile data[10] = 57849654
09-21 20:55:24.718 E/mm-camera-DENOISE(  208): [QCTK] WNR Y Profile data[11] = 161311416 Chroma Profile data[11] = 161311416
09-21 20:55:24.718 E/mm-camera-DENOISE(  208): [QCTK] WNR Y Profile data[12] = 1565943 Chroma Profile data[12] = 1565943
09-21 20:55:24.718 E/mm-camera-DENOISE(  208): [QCTK] WNR Y Profile data[13] = 2522653 Chroma Profile data[13] = 2522653
09-21 20:55:24.718 E/mm-camera-DENOISE(  208): [QCTK] WNR Y Profile data[14] = 24927283 Chroma Profile data[14] = 24927283
09-21 20:55:24.718 E/mm-camera-DENOISE(  208): [QCTK] WNR Y Profile data[15] = 104984676 Chroma Profile data[15] = 104984676
09-21 20:55:24.718 E/mm-camera-DENOISE(  208): [QCTK] WNR Y Profile data[16] = 6547424 Chroma Profile data[16] = 6547424
09-21 20:55:24.718 E/mm-camera-DENOISE(  208): [QCTK] WNR Y Profile data[17] = 13991254 Chroma Profile data[17] = 13991254
09-21 20:55:24.718 E/mm-camera-DENOISE(  208): [QCTK] WNR Y Profile data[18] = 63092262 Chroma Profile data[18] = 63092262
09-21 20:55:24.718 E/mm-camera-DENOISE(  208): [QCTK] WNR Y Profile data[19] = 204423936 Chroma Profile data[19] = 204423936
09-21 20:55:24.718 E/mm-camera-DENOISE(  208): [QCTK] WNR Y Profile data[20] = 2626840 Chroma Profile data[20] = 2626840
09-21 20:55:24.718 E/mm-camera-DENOISE(  208): [QCTK] WNR Y Profile data[21] = 3710134 Chroma Profile data[21] = 3710134
09-21 20:55:24.718 E/mm-camera-DENOISE(  208): [QCTK] WNR Y Profile data[22] = 24753796 Chroma Profile data[22] = 24753796
09-21 20:55:24.718 E/mm-camera-DENOISE(  208): [QCTK] WNR Y Profile data[23] = 108984156 Chroma Profile data[23] = 108984156
09-21 20:55:24.718 E/mm-camera-DENOISE(  208): wavelet_denoise_process: Wavelet Denoise Success
09-21 20:55:24.728 E/mm-camera-DENOISE(  208): wavelet_denoise_process: Wavelet Denoise Success
09-21 20:55:24.748 D/JKAT    (32103): onPictureTaken - PassAware-1379822124754.jpg
09-21 20:55:24.768 D/JKAT    (32103): Starting upload
09-21 20:55:24.778 D/dalvikvm(32103): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1703K, 58% free 4796K/11156K, paused 1ms+5ms, total 25ms
09-21 20:55:24.798 D/dalvikvm(32103): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 44K, 58% free 4783K/11156K, paused 24ms, total 24ms
09-21 20:55:24.798 I/dalvikvm-heap(32103): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.014MB for 1228816-byte allocation
09-21 20:55:24.798 W/SQLiteConnectionPool(32103): A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/data/com.jknipp.jkat/databases/theftMitigation' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
09-21 20:55:24.818 D/Ugh     (32103): For 4Old inProcess 0 New 1
09-21 20:55:24.818 I/DataHandler(32103): New inProcess! 1
09-21 20:55:24.828 D/JKAT    (32103): Upload call finished (it's async)
09-21 20:55:24.828 E/mm-libcamera2(  183): PROFILE HAL: stopPreview(): E: 1379822124.840284707
09-21 20:55:24.828 E/mm-camera(  208): config_MSG_ID_STOP_ACK: streamon_mask is not clear. Should not call PP_Release_HW
09-21 20:55:24.838 E/QCameraHWI(  183): android::status_t android::QCameraHardwareInterface::setPreviewWindow(preview_stream_ops_t*):Received Setting NULL preview window
09-21 20:55:24.838 E/QCameraHWI(  183): android::status_t android::QCameraHardwareInterface::setPreviewWindow(preview_stream_ops_t*): mPreviewWindow = 0x0x0, mStreamDisplay = 0x0x2a075988
09-21 20:55:24.838 W/QCameraHWI_Preview(  183):  Setting NULL preview window
09-21 20:55:24.838 I/CameraClient(  183): Destroying camera 1
09-21 20:55:24.838 E/mm-camera(  208): config_shutdown_pp Camera not in streaming mode. Returning.
09-21 20:55:24.838 E/mm-camera(  208): vfe_ops_deinit: E
09-21 20:55:24.898 I/JKAT    (32103): Released camera
09-21 20:55:24.898 W/AudioFlinger(  183): session id 76 not found for pid 183
09-21 20:55:24.898 W/AudioFlinger(  183): session id 77 not found for pid 183
09-21 20:55:25.218 E/libsensor1(  537): sensor1_open: Error in connect() errno=111 Connection refused
09-21 20:55:25.218 E/qcom_sensors_hal(  537): hal_reinit: sensor1_open returned EWOULDBLOCK. Daemon not ready, so will try again
09-21 20:55:25.218 E/qcom_sensors_hal(  537): hal_handle_broken_pipe: hal_reinit() failed ret=5
09-21 20:55:25.258 D/FileUpload(32103): onPostExecute
09-21 20:55:25.258 D/Ugh     (32103): For 4Old inProcess 1 New 0
09-21 20:55:25.258 I/FileUpload(32103): Server accepted upload
09-21 20:55:25.258 D/FileUpload(32103): {"MESSAGE":"Yup!","SUCCESS":"1"}
09-21 20:55:25.278 E/Sensors ( 5262): Mag cal opened lib /system/lib/libAKM.so
09-21 20:55:25.278 E/Sensors ( 5262): Mag cal init success
09-21 20:55:25.278 W/Sensors ( 5262): sns_sam_app.c(6394):sns_sam_reg_algo: Registering algo service 16, err 0
09-21 20:55:25.278 I/DataHandler(32103): New inProcess! 0
09-21 20:55:25.288 E/Sensors ( 5262): sns_debug_main.c(565):Debug Config File missing in EFS!
09-21 20:55:25.288 W/qcom_sensors_hal(  537): hal_sensor1_data_cb: SENSOR1_MSG_TYPE_RETRY_OPEN
09-21 20:55:25.298 E/qcom_sensors_hal(  537): hal_process_time_resp: Resetting rollover count from 0 to 0
09-21 20:55:27.260 D/DeviceAdminMgr(32103): Correct password observed. Falling back until next locktime.
```

And finally, the code:

Here is the code code from cameraInteraceActivity:

```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        BugTracker.initialize(this);

        thisActivity = this;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camerainterfaceactivity);

        // Some phones have 2 cameras some have 1. Pick the front camera, which is always the second camera if there's 2.
        mWhichCamera = (Camera.getNumberOfCameras() == 2 ? 1 : 0);

        // Create an instance of Camera
        mCamera = getCameraInstance(mWhichCamera, mCamera);

        if (mCamera != null) {
            // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
            mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera, mJpegCallback);

            FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
            preview.addView(mPreview);
        } else {
            finish(); // camera isn't available, nothing we can do about that.
        }
    }

    /**
     * A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object.
     */
    public static Camera getCameraInstance(int cameraChoice, Camera currentCamera) {
        Log.i("JKAT", "getCameraInstance called");
        if (currentCamera == null) {
            Camera c = null;
            try {
                c = Camera.open(cameraChoice); // attempt to get a Camera instance
                c.setDisplayOrientation(180);
                if (c == null)
                    Log.i("JKAT", "Returning new camera instance");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
                Log.e("JKAT", "Cannot find camera: " + e.getMessage());

            }
            return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
        } else {
            Log.i("JKAT", "Returning found camera instance");
            return currentCamera;
        }
    }
```

Here is stuff from the cameraPreview class that binds to a preview element and then physically takes the picture then writes the jpeg.

```
  public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.
        Log.d(TAG, "SurfaceChanged called");
        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null) {
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here

        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
            cameraInterfaceActivity.muteShutter();
            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mJpegCallback);
            cameraInterfaceActivity.unmuteShutter();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

So far I know my current implementation works on the droid 3, GS4, GS3, Atrix, Incredible 2 and various other devices. I do not know if my app will run on a stock Nexus 4 or any other device build of CyanogenMod. I would appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Can you try to narrow the issue down some? It doesn't even seem like a code issue right now.

Comment: Narrow it down how? I don't have a stock N4 or anything that can run CM. I'm running a private alpha on Google Play with only people I know in on the test

Comment: So, if you can't narrow it down, how do you expect us to?

Comment: Perhaps you had a suggestion...

Comment: Well, asking a specific coding question would be a start. Don't expect anyone to be able to do device using for you, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you take the 2nd frame, in case just the first frame is bad? Or add a 10ms timer and take the photo then. (Hackey work-around).

Also, try *NOT* setting things like orientation without verifying that the setting actually needs changing. On some hardware, "Orientation(180)" might write values to the camera module, then reset the camera for the changes to take effect. And maybe the first frame after reset is bad?  Or maybe that camera needs some time to do a light balance?

Comment: Problem is this app takes a photo just as the activity starts and then the activity terminates. I will try adding a delay to see if that fixes it. Also, I'll remove the orientation thing. It didn't work anyhow. (Images are coming out rotated)

Comment: I finally had the time to implement a variable delay via settings. The  tester no longer has no more issues even when he set his timer to 0 seconds... but I also did remove the Orientation call, so that must have been it. Thanks!